# How to check object value?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out something in my test page made for fun.
So, I can tell that I've got in my page object:

```
<b id="1i1">$</b>
```

Which can change by some innerHTML in my script (which works fine).
I want to check value of this object and compare it:

```
function buttonPress()
{
    if(document.getElementById("1i1").value == "$")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But output of `getElementById("1i1").value` in code above is `undefined`, not `"$"`.
How I can get string value from this object?

Comment: yes, use `value` property only for form inputs.

Comment: Oh god, I have no idea why this worked, but it's fine now. Thank you @AMember.

Answer (score 1):

try `innerHTML`

```
function buttonPress()
{
    if((document.getElementById("1i1").innerHTML) == "$")
    {
        return (document.getElementById("1i1").innerHTML);
    }
}

alert(buttonPress())
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4yQT/)

Comment: First of all, `innerHTML` does not contain the text, it contains the html. Second, when was jquery mentioned in the question?

Comment: jquery was for just show the result its

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML document has a Node for the bold tag and a [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) node. 
The `document.getElementById("1i1")` expression returns the bold tag. Now get the first text
 `.firstChild` and then the `.wholeText` to get the string as visible in your browser.

```
document.getElementById("1i1").firstChild.wholeText
```

The [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) is good to reading, and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) helps a lot when things get complicated.